# I am new to using Oracle, and I am trying to insert data in stored procedure for a table but the data is inserting in NULL values?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE   OUTPATIENT_DLTE_PRE_ADMIN  (send_app IN VARCHAR, 
                                           send_facility IN VARCHAR ,
                                           reciving_app IN VARCHAR ,
                                           reciving_facility IN VARCHAR ,
                                           sendcreateddtm IN VARCHAR )
                                           
AS

     l_send_app VARCHAR(227);
    l_send_facility VARCHAR(227);
    l_reciving_app VARCHAR(227);
    l_reciving_facility VARCHAR(227);
    l_sendcreateddtm VARCHAR(40);

BEGIN
            INSERT INTO OPS_DLTE_PRE_ADMIN (SEND_APP, 
                                                    SEND_FACLTY,  
                                                    RECEIVING_APP, 
                                                    RECEVING_FACILITY,
                                                    send_CREATE_DTTM )
 VALUES 

                                                    (l_send_app,
                                                        l_send_facility,
                                                        l_reciving_app,
                                                        l_reciving_facility,
                                                        l_sendcreateddtm);
```

when am inserting data in store procedure but am getting NULL values in the table ?

Comment: it does not appear you have assigned values to the variables used in the values clause.

Comment: Your procedure has input parameters. Either those input parameters need to be assigned to the local variables in the procedure or the parameters need to be used directly in the insert statement. 
Also, it is good practice to declare variables used in DML with a [%TYPE attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/TYPE-attribute.html). That way the variables will automatically adjust if there are any modifications to the table on which they are based.

`l_send_app OPS_DLTE_PRE_ADMIN.SEND_APP%TYPE;`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined local variables, which are not assigned. Either assign the input arguments to the corresponding local variables or use the passed arguments in the insert.

```
l_send_app VARCHAR(227)          :=  send_app         ;
l_send_facility VARCHAR(227)     :=  send_facility    ;
l_reciving_app VARCHAR(227)      :=  reciving_app     ;
l_reciving_facility VARCHAR(227) :=  reciving_facility;
l_sendcreateddtm VARCHAR(40)     :=  sendcreateddtm   ;
```

or

```
     INSERT INTO OPS_DLTE_PRE_ADMIN (SEND_APP, 
                                     SEND_FACLTY,  
                                     RECEIVING_APP, 
                                     RECEVING_FACILITY,
                                     send_CREATE_DTTM )
       VALUES 

                                     (send_app,
                                      send_facility,
                                      reciving_app,
                                      reciving_facility,
                                      sendcreateddtm);
```